# Executing class method callback results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, callback, segmentation-fault

I have two classes.
One is a parser that processes data and executes the appropriate callback function. 
The other is the class that must do some work with a serial stream to update fields.

Below I have the minimal example of what I'm doing. Auxiliary is the equivalent of the parser that saves the callback address and executes one callback function when needed. Primary is the class that feeds and get results from Auxiliary.

The minimal example works without an hitch. (code below)

```
#include <iostream>

namespace User
{

class Auxiliary
{
    public:
    Auxiliary( void )
    {
        my_c_style_function_pointer = nullptr;
    }

    void register_callback( void *my_c_style_function_pointer_arg )
    {
        this -> my_c_style_function_pointer = my_c_style_function_pointer_arg;
    }


    void execute_callback( int x )
    {
        //Create a pointer to function with no arguments and no return
        void (*my_function_ptr)(int);
        //promote the pointer to the right kind
        my_function_ptr = (void(*)(int))this -> my_c_style_function_pointer;
        //execute handler
        (*my_function_ptr)( x );
    }

    void *my_c_style_function_pointer;
};

class Primary
{
    public:

    Primary()
    {
        this -> g_myint[0] = 0;

        my_instance_of_auxiliary_class = Auxiliary();

        my_instance_of_auxiliary_class.register_callback( (void *)&this -> method_a_i_want_to_callback );
        //my_instance_of_auxiliary_class.register_callback( (void *)&this -> method_b_i_want_to_callback );
    }

    void method_a_i_want_to_callback( int x )
    {
        this -> g_myint[0] = x +1;
    }

    void method_b_i_want_to_callback( int x )
    {
        this -> g_myint[0] = x +10;
    }

    void method_that_executes_callback( int x )
    {
        my_instance_of_auxiliary_class.execute_callback( x );
    }

    void show( void )
    {
        std::cout << "content: " << this -> g_myint[0] << "\n";
    }

    Auxiliary my_instance_of_auxiliary_class;

    int g_myint[2];
};

} //End namespace: User


int main()
{
    User::Primary my_instance_of_primary_class = User::Primary();

    //TEST1: direct call. No problems here
    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_a_i_want_to_callback( 1000 );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();

    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_b_i_want_to_callback( 1000 ) ;
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();

    //TEST2:
    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_that_executes_callback( 1000 );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();


    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output of the minimal example, which is correct.

```
content: 1001
content: 1010
content: 1001

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.010 s
Press any key to continue.
```

My problem is that when I'm trying to execute a class method from its call back address in the bigger project, the callback jump to the right method but with a bogey base address, causing it to go into segmentation fault. (Below pictor before and after the jump.
[image: Seg Fault]

There are tons of questions about calling methods from their callback address, none helped me. I tried using typedef and macros to using std::bind to no avail.

As far as I understand, it may have something to do with the first hidden argument of class methods (this) not being properly encoded in the (void *), but if so I can't figure out why the minimal example works and the bigger project does not.

This is the full parser class code for reference:
https://github.com/OrsoEric/2019-06-17-Uniparser-V4
I built it for use in 8 bit microcontrollers, and is built around a void * array of c style functio pointers. I'd like not to touch the callback mechanism since it's meant to minimize memory footprint.

Comment: From a superficial look I think you are calling the callback-function like a free function. In the callback you are using `this->` however, but there is no `this` if you call it like a free function (how should the compiler know which object instance the callback belongs to?). I'm a bit in a hurry, so just a link, maybe you find a better solution with [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: std::function seems promising. The parser class is one I built for low power 8 bit microcontroller and is built around a void * array to store c-style function addresses. I can make it work by making wrapper function that calls the class methods, but that feels like a boiler plate. Is there a way to store a class method pointer inside a void *?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **std::function**

I looked into std::function as suggested. While powerful, this method has overhead in the call and performs dynamic allocation. If possible I want to avoid dynamic allocation.

### **wrapper function**

I found a way to make class member callback while storing the pointers in void *. The register method saves both the class instance address and a user privided method to make the address executable.

Below the original example code that is able to callback a class method. I'm not sure it's portable, but it seems to work on both my desktop compiler and embedded compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace User
{

//Auxiliary class can register and execute class methods as callback function. It's based around C style void * function pointers
class Auxiliary
{
    public:
    Auxiliary( void )
    {
        my_c_style_instance_pointer = nullptr;
        my_c_style_executor_pointer = nullptr;
    }

    //Registering a callback involves saving the base address of the function/class method and the address of a function that can execute it
    void register_callback( void *my_c_style_instance_pointer_arg, void *my_c_style_executor_pointer_arg )
    {
        cout << "Registering callback...";
        cout << " | Instance: " << my_c_style_instance_pointer_arg;
        cout << " | Executor: " << my_c_style_executor_pointer_arg << "\n";

        this -> my_c_style_instance_pointer = my_c_style_instance_pointer_arg;
        this -> my_c_style_executor_pointer = my_c_style_executor_pointer_arg;
    }

    //Executing a callback from void * base addresses involve calling the user defined executor function. That function can be a lambda
    void execute_callback( int x )
    {
        //The register method stores the instance pointer and the method pointer as void *
        //A third method meant to be passed as lambda takes care of specializing the void * pointers to actually execute the call
        cout << "Executing instance...";
        cout << " | Instance: " << my_c_style_instance_pointer;
        cout << " | Executor: " << my_c_style_executor_pointer << "\n";

        //Create a pointer to the executor lambda function
        void (*my_function_ptr)(void *, int);
        //promote the pointer to the right kind
        my_function_ptr = (void(*)(void *, int))this -> my_c_style_executor_pointer;
        //execute handler
        (*my_function_ptr)( my_c_style_instance_pointer, x );
    }

    void *my_c_style_instance_pointer;
    void *my_c_style_executor_pointer;
};

//This is a user class that has methods I want to callback
class Primary
{
    public:

    Primary()
    {
        this -> g_myint[0] = 0;

        this -> my_instance_of_auxiliary_class = Auxiliary();
    }

    void register_callback( void *instance_arg, void (*executor_lambda)(void *, int) )
    {
        /*
        g_my_boilerplate_instance_pointer = (void *)instance_arg;
        cout << "Registered Instance: " << g_my_boilerplate_instance_pointer << "\n";
        */

        cout << "Instance: " << instance_arg << "\n";
        cout << "Executor: " << executor_lambda << "\n";

        this -> my_instance_of_auxiliary_class.register_callback( instance_arg, (void *)executor_lambda );
    }

    void method_a_i_want_to_callback( int x )
    {
        cout << "\n" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        cout << "hidden argument (this): " << this << "\n\n";
        this -> g_myint[0] = x +1;
    }

    void method_b_i_want_to_callback( int x )
    {
        cout << "\n" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        cout << "hidden argument (this): " << this << "\n\n";
        this -> g_myint[0] = x +10;
    }

    void method_that_executes_callback( int x )
    {
        this -> my_instance_of_auxiliary_class.execute_callback( x );
    }

    void show( void )
    {
        cout << "content: " << this -> g_myint[0] << "\n";
    }

    void *xxx;

    Auxiliary my_instance_of_auxiliary_class;

    int g_myint[2];
}; //End class: Primary

} //End namespace: User

//Test bench
int main()
{
    User::Primary my_instance_of_primary_class = User::Primary();

    //TEST1: direct call
    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_a_i_want_to_callback( 1000 );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();

    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_b_i_want_to_callback( 1000 ) ;
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();

    //TEST2: callback
    //Register method takes the instance address and a wrapper to launch the method
    my_instance_of_primary_class.register_callback
    (
        (void *)&my_instance_of_primary_class,
        [](void *instance_ptr, int x)
        {
            cout<< "executing lambda... | Instance: " << instance_ptr << " | Argument: " << x << "\n";
            //Specialize the void * pointer
            User::Primary *primary_instance_ptr = (User::Primary *)instance_ptr;
            //Execute method
            //primary_instance_ptr -> method_a_i_want_to_callback( x );
            primary_instance_ptr -> method_b_i_want_to_callback( x );
        }
    );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_that_executes_callback( 1000 );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();

    my_instance_of_primary_class.register_callback
    (
        (void *)&my_instance_of_primary_class,
        [](void *instance_ptr, int x)
        {
            cout<< "executing lambda... | Instance: " << instance_ptr << " | Argument: " << x << "\n";
            //Specialize the void * pointer
            User::Primary *primary_instance_ptr = (User::Primary *)instance_ptr;
            //Execute method
            primary_instance_ptr -> method_a_i_want_to_callback( x );
            //primary_instance_ptr -> method_b_i_want_to_callback( x );
        }
    );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.method_that_executes_callback( 1000 );
    my_instance_of_primary_class.show();


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
method_a_i_want_to_callback
hidden argument (this): 0x28fefc

content: 1001

method_b_i_want_to_callback
hidden argument (this): 0x28fefc

content: 1010
Instance: 0x28fefc
Executor: 1
Registering callback... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Executor: 0x4013b0
Executing instance... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Executor: 0x4013b0
executing lambda... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Argument: 1000

method_b_i_want_to_callback
hidden argument (this): 0x28fefc

content: 1010
Instance: 0x28fefc
Executor: 1
Registering callback... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Executor: 0x4014d0
Executing instance... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Executor: 0x4014d0
executing lambda... | Instance: 0x28fefc | Argument: 1000

method_a_i_want_to_callback
hidden argument (this): 0x28fefc

content: 1001

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.022 s
Press any key to continue.
```

If anyone notices problems with this code, I'd be glad to know.